# Got empty list with Beautiful Soup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_lord_of_the_rings_the_return_of_the_king

I want to get TOMATOMETER  and AUDIENCE SCORE from that website,
but got an empty list.

```python
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
notices = soup.select('#tomato_meter_link > span.mop-ratings-wrap__percentage')
```

Comment: You mean `93%` and `86%`?

Comment: Or `Reviews Counted: 272, User Ratings: 34,679,279`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use last-child selector for span type with the parent class. This is using BeautifulSoup 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_lord_of_the_rings_the_return_of_the_king')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
ratings = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('h1.mop-ratings-wrap__score span:last-child')]
print(ratings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_lord_of_the_rings_the_return_of_the_king').text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> notices = soup.select('#tomato_meter_link > span.mop-ratings-wrap__percentage')
>>> notices
[<span class="mop-ratings-wrap__percentage">93%</span>]
```

How did you get `html` variable?